# QSystemTrayIcon in ubuntu, sni-qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

I built qt libraries (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2) and want to use them when building my application, and deploy them with my application.

I want my app to have system tray icon, so I'm trying to use QSystemTrayIcon class, but the icon doesn't show.

After some research I found out that it has something to do with sni-qt plugin. But I couldn't find any information on how to use it in my code. Or the qt libs must be patched to use it? Because if I link to qt libraries preinstalled in the system, the icon shows.

The question is how can I make system tray icon appear and function using my manually built qt libraries? Is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Qt will refuse to load a plugin compiled against a different Qt version (or with a different compiler, or a different Qt setup). Hence, you need to build that plugin as well using the same Qt version your application is using. Grab its sources and compile it.